# How to map structured grid data onto a regular grid efficiently?

Tags: data-structures

***Context:***

First of all, **my data**:

I am working with 3D data shaped onto a structured grid made of hexahedrons with for each 8 vertices and 12 edges.

The data I'm working on is cell data (and not point data).

Every cell and every vertex possess unique IDs.

For each cell I can list every other cell sharing a common vertex.
Consequently, if two cells share 2 vertices, they share an edge, and 4 vertices are needed to share a face.

There can be internal borders ("holes").

And finally the dataset is huge !

**My ultimate goal** is to apply operations on the whole dataset, based on the data of "neighbouring" cells.

Here is an example in 2D of a "cross" filter where I apply an operation onto the dark red cell based onto the data of the light red cells.

[image]

For this example, let's differentiate for a given cell, adjacent faces (sharing a common edge) and opposite faces (not sharing an edge).
Then, I need to find for every given "parent" cell which are the cells sharing a face with it, I will call them neighbours at rank 1. Then for every neighbour at rank 1, which are the cells (neighbours at rank 2) sharing their face opposed to the one shared with the initial parent cell...

This definition is really tedious and would need many "brute force" loops, so I thought of mapping every cell onto a rectilinear grid. I'm not modifying or interpolating the data, just changing the "representation" by storing it into a 3D matrix.

Thus if the parent cell now is on the line i and column j, I just need to loop on cells following something like :

```
for ii = i-2,i+2
    UsefullData(ii,j)
for jj = j-2, j+2
    UsefullData(i,jj)
```

[image]

Consequently, having the data mapped in such a way would allow for really easy manipulations, **the cross filter being just a simple example**. In a real case I would need to access up to the neighbour at rank 100, or user more elaborate filters than the "cross" filter defined above.

But it also have its caveats:
I don't know what would be the size of my mapping matrix i.e. border cells can "extrude" from the general "shape", or my grid could form a "C" shape, or possess inner holes...
I also don't know what would be the fastest (= less computing intensive) way to build it.

***The problem:***

I can't think of a robust and fast way to build this matrix, especially since I don't know how to define the maximum sizes of this matrix.

Maybe another type of connectivity table, easier to build but less "human readable" would also allow for easy manipulations ?

Also, I'm working with vtk and python, but  I don't thing this is relevant to the problem.
Thank You !